# Angular Popover error: this.listenMouseFunc is not a function at push.../node_modules/ng2-popover/PopoverContent.js.PopoverContent.ngOnDestroy

Tags: angular, popover, ng-bootstrap

I have implemented popover to display a comment on hover over an icon and to have a scrollbar. But when I navigate from one page to another (router link), I have the following error:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JRZMo.png)

This is my code:

```
<popover-content
  #myPopover
  placement="top"
  [animation]="true"
  [closeOnClickOutside]="true"
>
  <div style="max-height: 100px; min-width: 100px; overflow-y: auto;">
    {{ comment }}
  </div>
</popover-content>

<button
  type="button"
  class="btn"
  style="background-color: transparent;"
  (click)="showPopup()"
  data-toggle="modal"
  data-target="#modalComment"
  [popover]="myPopover"
  [popoverOnHover]="true"
  [popoverDisabled]="!comment"
  [popoverCloseOnClickOutside]="false"
  [popoverCloseOnMouseOutside]="true"
>
  <i *ngIf="comment" class="fa fa-lg fa-comment" style="color: orange;"></i>
  <i *ngIf="!comment" class="fa fa-lg fa-comment" style="color: silver;"></i>
</button>
```

I have imported the NgbPopoverModule.
I use: ngx-popover 0.0.16, Angular 8.

I expect to be able to navigate from one page to another without having this error or refresh.